# ClassNotFoundException oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper on tomcat TLD scanning. ojdbc7 maven dep (xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar transitive) causes this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat7, jstl, ojdbc

I am receiving an error when running my spring-boot application with embedded-tomcat (haven't tried with server tomcat yet).

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat 7 reflection failed
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.scan(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:590)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.SkipPatternJarScanner.scan(SkipPatternJarScanner.java:73)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.setEncoding(XMLReader.java:980)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.checkXMLDecl(XMLReader.java:3284)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:570)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:274)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:232)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:565)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:513)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.access$200(TldConfig.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig$TldJarScannerCallback.scan(TldConfig.java:300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:259)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:221)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

On further inspection, It appears as though the previous version of the orai18n.jar depended on by the ojdbc7 maven dep contained this class in vesion 11.2.0.3 but the newer (12.1.0.2) file does not contain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a conflict with xmlparserv2.
Try this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am using ojdbc8-production artifact and in my case exclusion is 
             <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
              <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
             </exclusion>

Answer (score 7):

After much hassle, I've found the root cause (Edit: Actually the better answer provided has a more appropriate cause/solution, see Serri's answer):

according to [this bug comment in spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8682#issuecomment-288092275) The Oracle `SaxParserFactory` impl and the (later run into after solving the first) `DocumentBuilderFactory` implementations are picked up instead of the default xerces impls. Changing the implementation using the `META-INF/services/<class-name>` files solved the issue:

in `my.jar`:

[image]

and each file:

```
// javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

// javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
```

This causes each service finder to resolve the default xerces implementation in the standard java library.

Comment: Is it okay to create `META-INF` folder and `services` folder if I don't have one in my Maven project under resources folder? Eclipse actually creates it under source folder if I try to create one under resource folder. 2) After creating two files inside `services` folder, should I just put   what you have mentioned just below `and each file` ?

Comment: Hi John, This should be fine, I use intellij myself but the resource and source folder should theorectically end up in the same directory structure alongside the classes anyway. taking a step back though, @EdouardSerri answer is probably the best way to fix this problem in general without having to create these files.

Comment: I edited the xmlparserv2 jar directly and it works like a charm, thanks @coderatchet!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the Oracle Jars installed under $CATALINA_HOME/lib to be able to set up a JNDI DB connection in Tomcat, simply removing xmlparserv2.jar from the $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

New change for xdb instead `com.oracle.jdbc` use: `com.oracle.ojdbc`.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
     <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
     <version>19.3.0.0</version>
     <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
               <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is as Serri said, except for the solution given by Serri I think if you use IntelliJ IDEA as a coding tool, please check Project Structure Artifacts to remove the dependency on xmlparserv2, this worked for me

[Remove conflicting dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh2lT.png)