# Oracle OJDBC driver throws NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, gradle

I'm getting the below error when using Oracles OJDBC Driver in my Spring Boot project when running on a tomcat 8.5 server (not the embedded tomcat)

> NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper

If I run it using the embedded tomcat everything works. Unfortunately I need it to run on a external container (I think it's called)

I generated my project from https://start.spring.io/

[image: start spring]

Everything is default except the oracle driver.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
      credentials {
        username = oracleUser
        password = oraclePass
    }
   url 'https://www.oracle.com/content/secure/maven/content'
  }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/centralized-sourcing-backend]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/centralized-sourcing-backend]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/i18n/util/LocaleMapper
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.setEncoding(XMLReader.java:990)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.checkXMLDecl(XMLReader.java:3542)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:580)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLReader.pushXMLReader(XMLReader.java:284)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:243)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1458)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml(WebXmlParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(FragmentJarScannerCallback.java:77)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1126)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 23 more
```

I'm running the project from Spring Tool Suite (STS) like this

[image: run]

I've found other people with the same issue, like these

- [ClassNotFoundException oracle.i18n.util.LocaleMapper on tomcat TLD scanning. ojdbc7 maven dep (xmlparserv2-12.1.0.2.jar transitive) causes this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916255/classnotfoundexception-oracle-i18n-util-localemapper-on-tomcat-tld-scanning-ojd)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8682

but I have no idea what they're talking about. This the first time working with Java and Spring and Oracle and Eclipse :(

Comment: I propose taking a look into your pom.xml, also take a look at this [Accessing Relational Data using JDBC with Spring :: Learn how to access relational data with Spring](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-relational-data-access)

Comment: I don't have a pom.xml file. As I understand it that's a Maven thing and I'm using Gradle

Comment: My bad didn't notice, unfortunately I haven't done much development with Grandle :(.

Comment: Those links are related to the problem you're having. The Oracle driver has its own XML parser, which is being picked up by Tomcat. It's an unholy mess, but the solution provided in that StackOverflow question should work for you. You will need to create the _META-INF/services_ files yourself and put them in the WAR. Not sure where they should go exactly, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916255/classnotfoundexception-oracle-i18n-util-localemapper-on-tomcat-tld-scanning-ojd) and not try to understand it.
Put some magic files in a magic location (`src/main/resources/META-INF/services/`) and poof it started working :/